# How can I compress pytorch transformer model?

Tags: performance, pytorch, compression, transformer-model

I have a model that contains BERTtokenizer and some transformer blocks.
Is there a way to compress a transformer model or ...?
Our model looks like this:
GPT(
(transformer): ModuleDict(
(wte): Embedding(129600, 768)
(wpe): Embedding(1024, 768)
(drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
(h): ModuleList(
(0-11): 12 x Block(
(ln_1): LayerNorm()
(attn): CausalSelfAttention(
(c_attn): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=2304, bias=False)
(c_proj): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=False)
(attn_dropout): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
(resid_dropout): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
)
(ln_2): LayerNorm()
(mlp): MLP(
(c_fc): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=False)
(c_proj): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=False)
(dropout): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
(gelu): GELU(approximate='none')
)
)
)
(ln_f): LayerNorm()
)
(lm_head): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=10048, bias=False)
)

I tried to prune it but it didn't work well.
I hope your detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

These type of optimizations require some knowledge to work propperly.

I'm not sure if you just want to save disk space, to reduce GPU / CPU memory consumption or to speed up the process.

While there aren't any magical modules that can drastically shrink your model by 75% without affecting accuracy, there are several general techniques worth exploring. However, it's important to note that their compatibility with different frameworks, architectures and devices may vary:

- **Pruning**: This technique transforms model weights into sparse matrices by removing insignificant connections. The inference might still be a normal Matmul, so a performance improvement deppends on the framework.
- **Weight Quantization**: It reduces the weight precision to FP16, INT8, or even lower, thereby reducing memory requirements.
- **Knowledge Distillation**: This method aims to compress a large model by training a smaller one using the weights of the original model as a teacher.
- **Weight Clustering**: This technique compresses the model by clustering the weights into N clusters, reducing the number of unique weight values.

Keep in mind that these techniques can be mixed! You can quantize and prune a distilled model, but i guess the model optimizer will crash sooner or later .

Comment: I see. Could you quantize this model, please? I hope that would be static quantization.